# How to do customized search?

Tags: support, search

I want to do a custom search, e.g question I cast a closure, and contains a keyword, but I don't know any tags other than `user:id`, where can I find them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're on the [Search Options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search) page, under "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options". The easiest way to get there is to do an empty search (just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search field)

In your case, there is no field for "question I cast a closure"; the closest is `closed:1` to match questions that are currently closed